# @media query being ignored

Tags: css, media-queries

I have two Media queries. One that has a max width of: 1919px and one that has a max-width of 2000px

The query that has the max-width of 1919px works but when using my 1080p (1920px) screen the max-width: 2000px query is completely ignored and the default css is used. I cannot figure out why this is? I've been trying to work out whats going on in the developer mode but still haven't got to the bottom of it. Other things that I have tried are playing around with min-width and max-width but still no luck.

```
 /*BEING IGNORED NOT WORKING*/
@media screen and (max-width: 2000px) { 

.left{
width: 60px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
}

.right{
width: 60px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
}


}
/* WORKS */

@media screen and (max-width: 1919px) {

.left{
position:absolute;
height:0px;
width:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}

.right{
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
width:0px;
}

  }
```

Comment: mine says: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: If you open your JavaScript console and type `innerWidth`, what’s the result?

Comment: Er, when you say the “default CSS is used”, do you mean the `max-width: 1919px` section is applied? Because unless your viewport spans the entire width of your monitor, with no window borders and no scrollbars, that’s to be expected on a screen that’s 1920px wide.

Comment: innerWidth says 1679, nice trick btw thanks. However If I change max-width: 1919px to max-width:1920px the css query applies on the laptop.

Comment: If you open up the styles inspector (right-click on either a `.left` or `.right` element and select “Inspect element”), which rules show up as applied and which are struck out?